# Troubles with BlazingText jsonlines Batch Transform

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have a jsonlines file that looks like this:

```
{"id":123,"source":"this is a text string"}
{"id":456,"source":"this is another text string"}
{"id":789,"source":"yet another string"}
```

When I run a BlazingText Batch Transform job on a file that just contains the source, it works. When trying to join the inputs and outputs, I get `Customer Error: Unable to decode payload: Incorrect data format. (caused by AttributeError)`.

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
bt_transformer = bt_model.transformer(
    instance_count = 1,
    instance_type = "ml.m4.xlarge",
    assemble_with = "Line",
    output_path = s3_batch_out_data,
    accept = "application/jsonlines"
)

bt_transformer.transform(
    s3_batch_in_data, 
    content_type = "application/jsonlines",
    split_type = "Line", 
    input_filter = "$.source", 
    join_source = "Input", 
    output_filter = "$['id', 'SageMakerOutput']"
)

bt_transformer.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

When applying "$.source" on {"id":123,"source":"this is a text string"}, the output is "this is a text string" instead of {"source":"this is a text string"} which is probably why you got a format error. I'm wondering why you need to do such filtering on a JSON input - doesn't the algorithm ignore unrecognized JSON fields automatically?

Comment: It doesn't seem to ignore unused fields. If I just use:
```{"source":"this is a text string"}
{"source":"this is another text string"}
{"source":"yet another string"}```

and

```bt_transformer.transform(
    s3_batch_in_data, 
    content_type = "application/jsonlines",
    split_type = "Line")```

it works, though then I don't have the original ids.

Comment: from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/batch-transform.html): "The predictions in an output file are listed in the same order as the corresponding records in the input file"